# SQL Server Add a Bit Column with 2 default values, and it should default to one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to add a new column Isactive with (data type bit, not null)
ANd Populate the column with:
1 = active
0 = not active (default value).
Thanks in Advance.

I tried this by searching old question : 
"

```
alter table tblname
    add (STATUS VARCHAR(15) default '0',
         constraint conSTATUS check (STATUS in ('1', '0')))
```

"
but how to set 1 = active  & 0 = not active.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply, I am working on this . Appreciate your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add a computed column.  This is not a constraint thing:

```
alter table NCT_UserRegistration
    add isactive as (case when status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end);
```

`bit` is not really a SQL data type (although some databases do support it.  An int should be fine for your purposes.

Comment: computed column is a good idea so +1, -10 for suggesting that `BIT` is "not really a SQL data type"

Comment: Curious what you mean that bit is not really a SQL datatype? A boolean is not a valid sql datatype for sure.

Comment: @SeanLange . . . Is a "bit" a "boolean"?

Comment: I would say that those are very different actually. A bit is a 1 or 0 where a boolean is true or false. In the sql universe the first is data and the second is logical. Different sides of the same coin I suppose. And since the "bit" datatype is not binary in the database universe it can't really be called a "bit". And a boolean, at least in t-sql, doesn't exist....but it sure would be handy at times.

Answer (score 1):

> but how to set 1 = active & 0 = not active

You don't set anything.
`STATUS` is a flag column and it can be translated in the presentation layer as you wish.
When you query the table use a `CASE` expression like this:

```
select
  case STATUS 
    when 0 then 'not active'
    when 1 then 'active'
  end
from tblname
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you wanted to know how will you add values true and false to the table. I will start from a demo sample of your table(just for example):

```
create table tblname(id int, name varchar(20))
```

I will insert one row:

```
insert into tblname values (1, 'Marc')
```

This select query `select * from tblname` will result:

```
| ID | name |
| 1  | Marc |
```

Then we alter the table and add a `BIT` column called `Isactive` (with the constraint from your question)

```
alter table tblname add 
   Isactive  bit default 0 not null, 
   constraint conSTATUS check (Isactive in ('1', '0'));
```

Because the default value is 0 then the row with ID = 1 and name = 'Marc' will have a new value of the column Isactive set to 0. But when you run this query `select * from tblname` again it will give you this results:

```
| ID | name | isactive |
| 1  | Marc | False    |
```

If you then insert another row in your table like this:

```
insert into tblname values (2, 'Ann', 1);
```

with this query `select * from tblname` your results will be:

```
| ID | name | isactive |
| 1  | Marc | False    |
| 1  | Ann  | True     |
```

I hope this helps.

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f2efaaaf12fafc179f2d316c1ecdb8d6)

P.S. More interesting thins about BIT type in SQLServer you can find here:
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-bit/

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi @Newbie, you are welcome. I hope it helped you ?

Comment: Yes, It helped me .Thanks So much.